# How to get the Average of a specific category and impute the missing values category wise with coresponding median

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Hi i have data as following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

## loading the data into data frame

```
X = pd.read_csv('demo.csv')
```

the two columns of interest are the Category and Totals column:

```
Category Totals estimates
A        2777    0.43
B        1003    0.26
D         NA     0.65
D        2638    0.17
B         NA     0.74
C        2196    0.13
D        2630    0.91
A         NA     0.39
C        2472    0.51
B        1090    0.12
C         NA     0.64
```

I can find the median of the category `A` as:

```
df.groupby('Category').Totals.median().loc['A']
```

I require help to achieve the below following:

1. I need to find median of all categories all at once and not one by one.
2. I need to then impute the missing values in `Totals` column by corresponding category median.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) here:

```
df['Totals'] = df.Totals.fillna(df.groupby('Category').Totals.transform('median'))
```

Or another way could be:

```
df['Totals'] = (df.set_index('Category').Totals
                  .fillna(df.groupby('Category').Totals.median()).values)
```

---

```
print(df)

   Category  Totals  estimates
0         A  2777.0       0.43
1         B  1003.0       0.26
2         D  2634.0       0.65
3         D  2638.0       0.17
4         B  1046.5       0.74
5         C  2196.0       0.13
6         D  2630.0       0.91
7         A  2777.0       0.39
8         C  2472.0       0.51
9         B  1090.0       0.12
10        C  2334.0       0.64
​
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `median` for `Series` with same size like original, so possible replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df.Totals = df.Totals.fillna(df.groupby('Category').Totals.transform('median'))
```

Alternative solution with lambda function:

```
df.Totals = df.groupby('Category').Totals.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
```

---

```
print (df)
   Category  Totals  estimates
0         A  2777.0       0.43
1         B  1003.0       0.26
2         D  2634.0       0.65
3         D  2638.0       0.17
4         B  1046.5       0.74
5         C  2196.0       0.13
6         D  2630.0       0.91
7         A  2777.0       0.39
8         C  2472.0       0.51
9         B  1090.0       0.12
10        C  2334.0       0.64
```